# AngularJS calling API giving injector error

Tags: angularjs, api, http

I'm having an injection error when i try to use $http to get a value from an API on my app. I'm including both the code of the module definition and the function which calls the Web API and the error in the browser console.

```
angular.module('mod-1').controller('Controller', ['$scope','http', 'APICM', '$q', '$filter', '$timeout', 'AppSettings'$modal', 'Dialog', 'title',
function ($scope, $http, API, $q, $filter, $timeout, AppSettings, $modal, Dialog, title) {

    $('.page-title').text(title);

    function getActiveStore() {
      $http.get("https://localhost:44300/api/store/active").success(
            function (response) {
                $scope.currentStore = response;
            })
    }
}
```

Error:
    Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/unpr?p0=httpProvider%20%3C-%20http
    at Error (native)
    at https://localhost:44300/Scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:6:453
    at https://localhost:44300/Scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:32:18
    at Object.c [as get] (https://localhost:44300/Scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:29:147)
    at https://localhost:44300/Scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:32:86
    at c (https://localhost:44300/Scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:29:147)
    at d (https://localhost:44300/Scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:29:324)
    at Object.instantiate (https://localhost:44300/Scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:30:482)
    at https://localhost:44300/Scripts/vendor/angular.min.js:59:495
    at https://localhost:44300/Scripts/vendor/angular-route.min.js:6:446

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot $ when declaring '$http':

```
angular.module('mod-1').controller('Controller', ['$scope','$http', 'APICM', '$q', '$filter', '$timeout', 'AppSettings', '$modal', 'Dialog', 'title',
function ($scope, $http, API, $q, $filter, $timeout, AppSettings, $modal, Dialog, title) {

    $('.page-title').text(title);

    function getActiveStore() {
      $http.get("https://localhost:44300/api/store/active").success(
            function (response) {
                $scope.currentStore = response;
            })
    }
}
```

This should fix the error you are getting.

Comment: @javier_el_bene - We all been there .. Try to understand how providers and injectables  work and understand angularjs weird stacktrace (: